# Visually categorizing table columns?

Tags: tables

In our data table, we have three types of columns. Let's call these Type A, B and C. There is only 1 column which is Type A, maybe 4-7 columns that are Type B and the rest are Type C (the least important).

Does anyone have suggestions for how to visually communicate these categories of columns? I thought about using an icon of sorts, but it seems a little bulk because our table is so crowded. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what these "types" are, so we could include some more relevant information in our reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You may colorize them as shown below as your wish of preference or depending upon the product's features like corporate identity, color contrast, etc. I didn't make any further arrangement with the table but you may also prefer to add outer boundaries for creating visually discrete spaces.

[image]